# Real profit after accounting for inflation

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation

A paragraph from [*Naked Money*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30231790-naked-money):

> Carl … bought a house for \$200,000 and sold it a year later for \$246,000 at a time when inflation was 25 percent … Carl makes a 23 percent gain on paper, but prices have gone up 25 percent, so in real terms he has suffered a 2 percent loss.

This seems wrong to me. The real value at which Carl sold the house is \$246,000 / 1.25 = \$196,800. This implies a $\frac{200,000-196,800}{200,000} = \frac{3,200}{200,000} =$ 1.6% loss. Even if the author has rounded up this figure to "2 percent", the calculation isn't a straightforward subtraction like the second sentence implies.

In fact, the author is not rounding, but straightforwardly substracting. This is clear from his second example:

> Adam … bought a house for \$200,000 and sold it a year later for \$154,000 after prices had fallen by 25 percent. … Adam has lost 23 percent on paper, but prices have fallen 25 percent, so he’s made a 2 percent gain when deflation is taken into account.

The real value at which Adam sold his house is \$154,000 / 0.75 = \$205,333.33, implying a 2.67% gain (which should be rounded up to 3%, not down).

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: It's a book, not a scientific paper,  using a commonly used linear [approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_versus_nominal_value_(economics)#Real_growth_rate).